# What does the console output for 'Object($)' mean?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-devtools, firebug

I have a simple html page with nothing but a jquery include..

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  HELLO WORLD JQUERY
</body>
```

When I run this page and open developer tools in Chrome and do 'Object($)' on the console, I get the following...

```
function (a,b){return new m.fn.init(a,b)}
```

whereas in Firebug I see..

```
function(a, b)
```

Could someone tell me what I am looking at here and why its different per browser when they are both reading the same jQuery library?

Comment: This depends about browser console outputiing format. Both are the same

Comment: It's just a stylistic difference between the browsers. Chrome gives you the function declaration and the body, whereas Firebug just shows the declaration. Both are referring to the same thing.